# Wait for successful response from API Call

Tags: python, json, httprequest, urllib2

I am using Yahoo Api, I have implemented random sleep method in addition to that I have added hard sleeps but still I am unable to figure how I can just wait or try again if I don't get a response at first attempt.

For an example the code that I have put below, fails at some users, totally randomly. After it fails I take the url on my browser and it works like a charm. So my questions is why? and How can I resolve this? or can I improve this code to do do another request after a hard sleep (Only if thats a good approach)

I have few more information which I forgot to add, I changed the code to get my http success code:

```
print urlobject.getcode()
```

and it returns 200, but no json, as some suggested this might be throttle.

*Note: I have removed my appid(Key) from the url*

```
# return the json question for given question id
def returnJSONQuestion(questionId):
    randomSleep()
    url = 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?appid=APPIDREMOVED8&question_id={0}&output=json'
    format_url = url.format(questionId)
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(format_url)
        urlobject = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        time.sleep(10)
        jsondata = json.loads(urlobject.read().decode("utf-8"))
        print jsondata
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.code
        logging.exception("Exception")
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.reason
        logging.exception("Exception")
    except(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError,ValueError):
        print 'Question ID ' + questionId + ' Decode JSON has failed'
        logging.info("This qid didn't work " + questionId)
    return jsondata
```

Comment: It would be great, if you'll add the exact fail message

Comment: WOW Thanks for so many FANTASTIC answers!. I am going to try an implement one of those and see. I have no idea which answer I should pick they are all brilliantly explained hope full everyone get votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alrighty, first up, a few points that do not directly answer your question, but may be helpful:

1) I'm pretty sure there's never any need to wait between calling urllib2.urlopen and reading the returned addinfourl object. The examples at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples do not feature any such sleep.

2)

```
json.loads(urlobject.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

can be simplified to just

```
json.load(urlobject)
```

which is simpler and more readable.
Basically, .load takes a file-like object as an argument, whereas .loads takes a string. You may have thought that it was necessary to read() the data first in order to decode it from utf-8, but this is in fact no problem, because .load assumes by default that the object it is reading is ascii or utf-8 encoded (see http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load).

3) It may not matter for your present purposes, but I'd regard your exception handling here as bad. If anything goes wrong during the "try:" block, then the variable jsondata will not have been assigned. Then when we try to return it after the end of the try/except blocks, a NameError will be raised due to trying to use the unassigned variable. That means that if some other function in your application calls returnJSONQuestion and an exception occurs, then it will be a NameError, and not the original exception, that the outer function sees, and any tracebacks the outer function generates will not point to the spot where the real problem occurred. This could easily cause confusion when trying to figure out what has gone wrong. It would be better, therefore, if all your 'except' blocks here finished with 'raise'.

4) In Python, it's a good idea to put comments saying what a function does as docstrings (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) instead of as comments above the function.

Anyway, to **actually answer your question**...

You can get a seemingly random URLError when trying to open a URL for all kinds of reasons. Maybe there was a bug on the server during the handling of your request; maybe there was a connection problem and some data dropped; maybe the server was down for a few seconds while one of its admins changed a setting or pushed an update; maybe something else entirely. I've noticed after doing a little web development that some servers are much more reliable than others, but I figure that for most real-world purposes, you probably don't need to worry about why. The simplest thing to do is just to retry the request until you succeed.

With all the above in mind, the code below will probably do what you need:

```
def returnJSONQuestion(questionId):
    """return the json question for given question id"""

    url = 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?appid=APPIDREMOVED8&question_id={0}&output=json'
    format_url = url.format(questionId)
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(format_url)

        # Try to get the data and json.load it 5 times, then give up
        tries = 5
        while tries >= 0:
            try:
                urlobject = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                jsondata = json.load(urlobject)
                print jsondata
                return jsondata
            except:
                if tries == 0:
                    # If we keep failing, raise the exception for the outer exception
                    # handling to deal with
                    raise
                else:
                    # Wait a few seconds before retrying and hope the problem goes away
                    time.sleep(3) 
                    tries -= 1
                    continue

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.code
        logging.exception("Exception")
        raise
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.reason
        logging.exception("Exception")
        raise
    except(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError,ValueError):
        print 'Question ID ' + questionId + ' Decode JSON has failed'
        logging.info("This qid didn't work " + questionId)
        raise
```

Hope this helps! If you're going to be making a lot of different web requests in your program, you'll probably want to abstract out this 'retry request on exception' logic into a function somewhere so that you don't need to have the boilerplate retry logic mixed in with other stuff. :)

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer any chance you could tell me why I would get an error like this from this method?

Comment: SO here is the deal you told not to use json.loads(urlobject.read().decode("utf-8")) but without this I am not getting any json data so I guess decode should take place.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do json.loads(urlobject) when in fact you need json.load(urlobject). json.loads takes a string as an argument; json.load takes a file-like object, such as an addinfourl object.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the fail reason, this could be some Yahoo throttling limits (or may be not), but actually, it's a good idea to save question ids, which cause fails and retry later.

This could be easily done. Modify function a little bit:

```
def returnJSONQuestion(questionId):
    randomSleep()
    jsondata = None
    url = 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?appid=APPIDREMOVED8&question_id={0}&output=json'
    format_url = url.format(questionId)
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(format_url)
        urlobject = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        time.sleep(10)
        jsondata = json.loads(urlobject.read().decode("utf-8"))
        print jsondata
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.code
        logging.exception("Exception")
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.reason
        logging.exception("Exception")
    except(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError,ValueError):
        print 'Question ID ' + questionId + ' Decode JSON has failed'
        logging.info("This qid didn't work " + questionId)
    return jsondata
```

And in any fail case this function will return you None. So, you can check result, and if it's None — store question id in some list, and then retry it about 3 times. Maybe it will be more lucky second time.

Of course, you also can modify the function so, it retry request few times simultaniously on error, but first solution looks more preferable for me.

BTW, setting 'User-Agent' header to some real browser value — usually also a good idea in such cases, for example Google doesn't return results in many case for such "robo-parsers"

Comment: Actually I am already doing what you have suggested I am logging all the failing questions and re run them again. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've run into issues like this a lot.  I usually implement my API request wrapper or browser "get" like this:

```
def get_remote( url , attempt=0 ):
   try :
       request = urllib2.Request(format_url)
       urlobject = urllib2.urlopen(request)
       ...
       return data
   except urllib2.HTTPError , error:
       if error.code in ( 403 , 404 ):
           if attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS :
                return get_remote( url , attempt=attempt+1 )
       raise
```

based on the url or the attempt, i'll also change the request params.  for example, certain websites will block Python identified browsers - so I'll swap in the user agent for Firefox if they match a regex.  alternatively: if something fails the first attempt, I might always try Firefox/Safari on the second request, or implement a random timeout between subsequent attempts.

Comment: This will do the job, but personally:
1) I wouldn't use recursion here when iteration will do fine
2) I wouldn't limit myself to catching only retrying on HTTPError, and definitely wouldn't limit myself to only retrying on certain error codes; httplib.IncompleteRead and various forms of URLError that are not instances of HTTPError (example: Connection Refused error) are also commonly transient problems worth retrying on.
3) I'd sleep for a few seconds between attempts. Everyday browsing tells me that sites sometimes go down for a few seconds; a delay between retries helps handle that.

Comment: That was just sample code to illustrate the point.  I found recursion works best, because ( and I omitted this from the example ) as there tends to be a lot of misc redirects or random reformatting that needs to get done as you process the URL.  for example, you might process a bit.ly link that points to a nyti.ms link that points to a newyorktimes.com article that then tries to trigger a paywall redirect ( although the content is still available ).  by splitting the function out, it's easier to call from misc helper functions i dispatch to.

Comment: Hmm. Care to elaborate on how using recursion instead of iteration provides benefits when you're chaining helper functions? I don't see how that follows, and think you're wrong on this point, although I may simply be missing something obvious (wouldn't be the first time!)

Comment: It's just a personal preference for some of my spidering / api projects.  Performance , readability , etc is pretty much on par with yours.